# Create a sepBy parser combinator sensitive to the indentation of the first parser

Tags: f#, indentation, fparsec

Via FParsec and using this [lib](https://github.com/manio143/IndentFParsec) (whose code, which is quite short, has been copied to the end of the question), I'm trying to design a `sepBy`-like parser that is sensitive to the indentation of the first parser passed in argument. Typically, if I give this: `indentedSepBy (pstring "Example") (pchar '.')`, I would like this type of program to be acceptable:

```
Example
  .Example
  .Example.Example
  .Example.Example.Example
  .Example
```

But not this one:

```
Example
.Example
.Example.Example
.Example
```

So that the very first position (and so the very first parser) setting the indentation of the rest. To do this, I just tried a simple rewrite using FParsec's default sepBy parser by applying it to the indentation lib, I get this:

```
open FParsec
open IndentParsec

let indentSepBy p sep =
    parse {
        let! pos = getPosition
        return! sepBy (greater pos p) (greater pos sep)
    }

let test = indentSepBy (pstring "Example") (pchar '.')
let text = "Example.Example" (*Simple for start*)
```

Applying this, I get the following error message (from FParsec):

> ```
> "Error in Ln: 1 Col: 16
> Example.Example
>                ^
> Note: The error occurred at the end of the input stream.
> Expecting: '.'
> "
> ```

If I remove the indentation-related parsers,

```
let indentSepBy p sep = (*so it's just trivially equivalent to the sepBy parser*)
    parse {
        let! pos = getPosition
        return! sepBy p sep
    }
```

The problem no longer arises and the result is what we expected. Therefore, I do not understand which parameter causes this error. It seems quite likely that it is a problem in the indentation lib, but I can't figure it out... Here is the lib in question, which I have shortened to the essentials:

```
open FParsec

module IndentParser =
    type Indentation =
        | Fail
        | Any
        | Greater of Position
        | Exact of Position
        | AtLeast of Position
        | StartIndent of Position
        member this.Position =
            match this with
            | Any
            | Fail -> None
            | Greater p -> Some p
            | Exact p -> Some p
            | AtLeast p -> Some p
            | StartIndent p -> Some p

    type IndentState<'T> = { Indent: Indentation; UserState: 'T }
    type IndentParser<'T, 'UserState> = Parser<'T, IndentState<'UserState>>

    let indentState u = { Indent = Any; UserState = u }
    let runParser p u s = runParserOnString p (indentState u) "" s

    let runParserOnFile p u path =
        runParserOnFile p (indentState u) path System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

    let getIndentation: IndentParser<_, _> =
        fun stream ->
            match stream.UserState with
            | { Indent = i } -> Reply i

    let putIndentation newi: IndentParser<unit, _> =
        fun stream ->
            stream.UserState <- { stream.UserState with Indent = newi }
            Reply(Unchecked.defaultof<unit>)

    let failf fmt = fail << sprintf fmt

    let acceptable i (pos: Position) =
        match i with
        | Any _ -> true
        | Fail -> false
        | Greater bp -> bp.Column < pos.Column
        | Exact ep -> ep.Column = pos.Column
        | AtLeast ap -> ap.Column <= pos.Column
        | StartIndent _ -> true

    let nestableIn i o =
        match i, o with
        | Greater i, Greater o -> o.Column < i.Column
        | Greater i, Exact o -> o.Column < i.Column
        | Exact i, Exact o -> o.Column = i.Column
        | Exact i, Greater o -> o.Column <= i.Column
        | _, _ -> true

    let tokeniser p =
        parse {
            let! pos = getPosition
            let! i = getIndentation

            if acceptable i pos
            then return! p
            else return! failf "incorrect indentation at %A" pos
        }

    let nestP i o p =
        parse {
            do! putIndentation i
            let! x = p

            do! notFollowedBy (tokeniser anyChar)
                <?> (sprintf "unterminated %A" i)

            do! putIndentation o

            return x
        }

    let indented<'a, 'u> i (p: Parser<'a, _>): IndentParser<_, 'u> =
        parse {
            do! putIndentation i
            do! spaces
            return! tokeniser p
        }

    let exact<'a, 'u> pos p: IndentParser<'a, 'u> = indented (Exact pos) p
    let greater<'a, 'u> pos p: IndentParser<'a, 'u> = indented (Greater pos) p
    let atLeast<'a, 'u> pos p: IndentParser<'a, 'u> = indented (AtLeast pos) p
    let any<'a, 'u> pos p: IndentParser<'a, 'u> = indented Any p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two problems here:

1. You're requiring the first `"Example"` to be indented beyond itself, which is impossible. You should instead let the first parser succeed regardless of the current position.
2. `greater` is not atomic, so when it fails, your parser is left in an invalid state. This might or might not be considered a bug in the library. In any case, you can make it atomic via `attempt`.

With that in mind, I think the following parser does roughly what you want:

```
let indentSepBy p sep =
    parse {
        let! pos = getPosition
        let! head = p
        let! tail =
            let p' = attempt (greater pos p)
            let sep' = attempt (greater pos sep)
            many (sep' >>. p')
        return head :: tail
    }
```

You can test this as follows:

```
let test =
    indentSepBy (pstring "Example") (pchar '.')

let run text =
    printfn "***"
    runParser (test .>> eof) () text
        |> printfn "%A"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    run "Example.Example"      // success
    run "Example\n.Example"    // failure
    run "Example\n .Example"   // success
    0
```

Note that I've forced the `test` parser to consume the entire input via `eof`. Otherwise, it will falsely report success when it can't in fact parse the full string.